# Factory data reset

Tags: samsung

I have done a factory reset and had the Back up my data and Automatic restore on. But I login with my other Google account first by mistake and now that I have logged in with the Google account that I had when I made ​​the recovery I can not find my photos. When I did that so I took out the microSD card. Is my pictures away now , or is that a way to restore them ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Backup my data and automatic restore, doesn't necessarily means all data. It really depends on the Android version. In the case of pictures, it should be backed up to Picasa. Check it out first there if it's available, then you could proceed with another forced sync to force the download of your pictures.

Comment: I know know that, i allready check there and google photos, but cant fint anything, i guess ther is no other way, thinks for your answer anyway